# How to create user and roles using api for wso2 bps

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-business-process

Is there any API for creating wso2 bps users and roles.

In */repository/conf/carbon.xml i configured HideAdminServiceWSDLs to false

```
<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>
```

And restarted the server.

My server port(offest is 0) is 9443 and in browser if I call url as below it is giving 404.

```
https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RemoteUserStoreManagerService` SOAP service for this.

See [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs) for details.

**Edit:**

Seems `RemoteUserStoreManagerService` is not available in BPS. Instead, try to use `UserAdmin` service.

Comment: It comes from the shared kernel. So it should be available. Make sure to do step 1.

Comment: I have updated the question with steps I followed but then also I am getting 404.